# Heroku login - There was a problem with your login

Tags: heroku

I am trying to login into my heroku account but that fails with `There was a problem with your login.`
I have already reset my password and tried logging in from four different browsers on three different machines, to no avail.

I would raise a ticket at the heroku helpdesk but that is not possible without login. Any idea how to proceed on this? I haven't found a traditional hotline to call either...

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm facing the same issue right now

Comment: Same issue with me as well few days back. I had to reset the password to fix this.

Answer (score 6):

Heroku experienced a major security incident last month and further determined that an "attack agent" exfiltrated hashed passwords. Because of this incident, Heroku reset all user passwords on May 4.

From the [incident page](https://status.heroku.com/incidents/2413):

> Salesforce is ensuring all Heroku user passwords are reset and potentially affected credentials are refreshed. We have rotated internal Heroku credentials and put additional detections in place.

For now, a password reset to something other than your last password is not a bad idea.

Answer (score 3):

Resetting my password worked for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: How am I supposed to reset password if I can't even login? It is a spiral .